# App crash Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL) Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, itunes

My app was recently rejected as the app crashed on launch by beta testers but when running it in development provisioning profile this does not happen.May I know what this crash log mean when and how to solve it ?

Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness   We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note: 
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code
>   0x8badf00d Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog
>   transgression: com.app.appname exhausted real (wall clock) time
>   allowance of 19.03 seconds |  | ProcessVisibility: Foreground |
>   ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create |
>   WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed
>   total CPU time (seconds): 25.420 (user 25.420, system 0.000), 42%
>   CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 1.125, 2% CPU" | )
>   Triggered by Thread:  0

Comment: can you show us what you do in the `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method? that must be a really messy one, if watchdog complains about it.

Comment: I have a similar problem. The app works on the simulator but hangs on the launch screen on an iPad (iOS 12 and 12.01). It doesn't even get as far as `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. The CPU is idle. When launched from Xcode it hangs indefinitely. When launched from the device it is killed after 20 seconds with the above error.

Comment: In my case it turns out the problem was due to an `initialize` method on a category being run on start-up. This method was calling `[NSLocale currentLocale]`, which seemed to lead to a deadlock, presumably because the locale is not available at that point on a device but is on a simulator.

Answer (score 21):

Since you've got error code `0x8badf00d`:

> The exception code 0x8badf00d indicates that an application has been
>   terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. The application
>   took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events. One
>   common cause of this is doing synchronous networking on the main
>   thread. Whatever operation is on Thread 0: needs to be moved to a
>   background thread, or processed differently, so that it does not block
>   the main thread.

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your application is terminated immediately, it will be iOS12 (or Beta) problem.

In my case, I am using AD-HOC (distribution provision profile) to test on several users. When users upgrade to iOS12, the application terminates immediately when users launch the application.
Also, when I upgrade to iOS12 and launch the application, the application terminates immediately.

In my case the following LOG:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, process-launch watchdog transgression: com.keyholetv.jp.i-keyholetv2 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 20.00 seconds |  | ProcessVisibility: Unknown | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: process-launch | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 2.910 (user 2.910, system 0.000), 7% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.000, 0% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

It looks like that iOS12 changes to handle a distribution provision profile. I am not sure that this is BUG on iOS12 or not.