# iOS App Got Rejected multiple times due to keychain issue

Tags: ios, keychain

Our iOS app got rejected multiple times due to `keychain` issue.
Attaching crash logs below :

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ae2e20f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ae2e15a0 mach_msg + 72
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae147880 _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 500
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae147d10 dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply$VARIANT$mp + 52
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001ae3a6a04 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 204
5   Security                        0x00000001af3b7edc securityd_message_with_reply_sync + 96
6   Security                        0x00000001af3b845c securityd_send_sync_and_do + 80
7   Security                        0x00000001af40e414 __SecItemCopyMatching_block_invoke_2 + 236
8   Security                        0x00000001af40d2f4 __SecItemAuthDoQuery_block_invoke + 312
9   Security                        0x00000001af40bc60 SecItemAuthDo + 124
10  Security                        0x00000001af40c5f4 SecItemAuthDoQuery + 504
11  Security                        0x00000001af40e31c __SecItemCopyMatching_block_invoke + 104
12  Security                        0x00000001af40a284 SecOSStatusWith + 48
13  Security                        0x00000001af40c9dc SecItemCopyMatching + 332
14  FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000101bc131c -[FBSDKKeychainStore dataForKey:] + 250652 (FBSDKKeychainStore.m:0)
15  FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000101bc0f28 -[FBSDKKeychainStore dictionaryForKey:] + 249640 (FBSDKKeychainStore.m:0)
16  FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000101b8b9f4 -[FBSDKAccessTokenCacheV3_17 accessToken] + 31220 (FBSDKAccessTokenCacheV3_17.m:0)
17  FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000101b8b240 __36-[FBSDKAccessTokenCache accessToken]_block_invoke + 29248 (FBSDKAccessTokenCache.m:42)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ae639964 -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 144
19  FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000101b8b170 -[FBSDKAccessTokenCache accessToken] + 29040 (FBSDKAccessTokenCache.m:48)
20  FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000101b95d4c -[FBSDKApplicationDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 73036 (FBSDKApplicationDelegate.m:0)
21  MyApp                           0x0000000100353ab0 0x100284000 + 850608
22  MyApp                           0x0000000100356108 0x100284000 + 860424
23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001da894020 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 412
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001da895784 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3352
```

I am unable to figure out an issue. When i run app on device its working fine. But when we submit our app to the appStore, App got rejected saying :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: com.mt.MyApp exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 16.92 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 41.120 (user 41.120, system 0.000), 69% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 2.593, 4% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827809/app-rejection-crash-report-says-failed-to-scene-create-in-time-badf00d-what

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186258/app-crash-exception-type-exc-crash-sigkill-termination-reason-namespace-spri
Seems to be the same crash identifier.  Take a look for any Async call running on main thread that blocks your app launch.  Especially if that call is going to some Ip which could not be accessed all around the world ;P

Comment: Thanks  @VikasKrishnan But i have check, there is no async call

Comment: @ShrutiThombre That seems weird, then i think now its time to check for any deprecated calls or, is there any waiting for any info that blocks the app from launching...

Comment: Or else as you should verify any of your keychain related mechanism is being called in loop or does that take too much time.  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-EXCEPTION_INFO

Comment: @VikasKrishnan I have already tried above solution, but didn't get any success

Comment: You need to show some code, but it seems you are creating a deadlock on launch and our app is being killed by the watchdog. Test a TestFlight build. Test on a device that has never had your app installed before (or has been erased)