# Random Crash on IOS unity game

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash

I am building for IOS and after 20 days of torture the game is now working. The problem is it only works 50 % of the time. The other 50% it crashes on startup, this is the error that is returning in the device log. Any idea what might bring that ? I deleted facebook, firebase and googlesignin libraries because they didn't want to work at all in the ios build.
What happens is I open the game and i get a black screen for a bit. Then it closes the game and this error returns. On the first build form XCode it works and opens correctly. Any ideas ?

```
    Incident Identifier: 8112E4E8-3C9D-4DE3-A414-1AF905C63A00
    CrashReporter Key:   cbb6618220f871820f24baa58e3e282b833a7cca
    Hardware Model:      iPhone9,3
    Process:             dragononlinemmorpg [559]
    Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97F19A54-D4EA-4D20-94BA-DF88D87C9D8E/dragononlinemmorpg.app/dragononlinemmorpg
    Identifier:          nedi.game.dragononlinemmorpg
    Version:             5.2 (5.2)
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    Role:                Foreground
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]
    Coalition:           nedi.game.dragononlinemmorpg [598]
    
    
    Date/Time:           2021-01-17 23:01:00.6253 +0200
    Launch Time:         2021-01-17 23:00:40.4692 +0200
    OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.3 (18C66)
    Release Type:        User
    Baseband Version:    5.01.01
    Report Version:      104
    
    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
    Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
    Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, <RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:process-launch watchdog transgression: application<nedi.game.dragononlinemmorpg>:559 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 20.00 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: process-launch | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 6.820 (user 6.820, system 0.000), 17% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.171, 0% CPU" | ) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>
    Triggered by Thread:  0
    
    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c334d290 __ulock_wait + 8
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001970515a4 _dlock_wait + 52
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001970514e4 _dispatch_once_wait$VARIANT$mp + 112
    3   UIKitCore                       0x0000000199915fa4 -[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader _loadInitializationContext] + 120
    4   UIKitCore                       0x0000000199916270 -[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader applicationInitializationContext] + 28
    5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001998fe9a8 -[_UIScreenInitialDisplayConfigurationLoader initialDisplayContext] + 176
    6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001998fec84 +[UIScreen initialize] + 124
    7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ab7da064 CALLING_SOME_+initialize_METHOD + 20
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ab7e00b0 initializeNonMetaClass + 712
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ab7e1410 initializeAndMaybeRelock+ 37904 (objc_class*, objc_object*, mutex_tt<false>&, bool) + 300
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ab7ef52c lookUpImpOrForward + 856
    11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ab7da820 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 64
    12  UIKitCore                       0x0000000199916764 _UIGetCurrentFallbackTraitCollection + 96
    13  UIKitCore                       0x000000019a1b7f18 UIViewCommonInitWithFrame + 580
    14  UIKitCore                       0x000000019a1b7c7c -[UIView initWithFrame:] + 124
    15  WebKit                          0x00000001a30db4c4 -[WKWebView initWithFrame:configuration:] + 48
    16  WebKit                          0x00000001a30e2e94 -[WKWebView initWithFrame:] + 92
    17  UnityFramework                  0x0000000107f887b4 +[UniWebView load] + 24676276 (UniWebView.m:125)
    18  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ab7e825c load_images + 944
    19  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001970dc0f4 invocation function for block in dyld3::AllImages::runInitialzersBottomUp+ 65780 (dyld3::closure::Image const*) + 220
    20  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001970cee4c dyld3::closure::Image::forEachImageToInitBefore(void + 11852 (unsigned int, bool&) block_pointer) const + 92
    21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001970dcb28 dyld3::AllImages::loadImage+ 68392 (Diagnostics&, char const*, unsigned int, dyld3::closure::DlopenClosure const*, bool, bool, bool, bool, void const*) + 776
    22  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001970dc678 dyld3::AllImages::dlopen+ 67192 (Diagnostics&, char const*, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, void const*, bool) + 872
    23  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001970de294 dyld3::dlopen_internal+ 74388 (char const*, int, void*) + 368
    24  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001970d1590 dlopen_internal+ 21904 (char const*, int, void*) + 108
    25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001973d1048 _CFBundleDlfcnLoadFramework + 136
    26  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001973a2984 _CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError + 376
    27  Foundation                      0x000000019863fba8 -[NSBundle loadAndReturnError:] + 332
    28  dragononlinemmorpg              0x0000000104df7c94 UnityFrameworkLoad() + 31892 (main.mm:12)
    29  dragononlinemmorpg              0x0000000104df7d98 main + 32152 (main.mm:25)
    30  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001970cd568 start + 4
    
    Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.uikit.applicationSupportClient
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c334c66c __psynch_mutexwait + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dfba4358 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 88
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dfba42ac _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow$VARIANT$mp + 224
    3   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001970de16c dyld3::dlopen_internal+ 74092 (char const*, int, void*) + 72
    4   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001970d1590 dlopen_internal+ 21904 (char const*, int, void*) + 108
    5   SoftLinking                     0x00000001d7be5f30 _sl_dlopen_audited + 44
    6   BoardServices                   0x00000001afd8338c __34+[BSServiceManager sharedInstance]_block_invoke + 860
    7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001970ae280 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001970522f4 _dispatch_once_callout + 28
    9   BoardServices                   0x00000001afd8302c +[BSServiceManager sharedInstance] + 64
    10  BoardServices                   0x00000001afd7c024 +[BSServiceConnection _connectionWithEndpoint:clientContextBuilder:] + 316
    11  UIKitServices                   0x000000019b21ecb0 __44-[UISApplicationSupportClient _remoteTarget]_block_invoke + 204
    12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001970ae280 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019705db8c _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
    14  UIKitServices                   0x000000019b21ebac -[UISApplicationSupportClient _remoteTarget] + 140
    15  UIKitServices                   0x000000019b21e4c8 -[UISApplicationSupportClient applicationInitializationContextWithParameters:] + 180
    16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001999160f8 __63-[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader _loadInitializationContext]_block_invoke_2 + 224
    17  UIKitCore                       0x0000000199916010 __UIAPPLICATION_IS_LOADING_INITIALIZATION_INFO_FROM_THE_SYSTEM__ + 20
    18  UIKitCore                       0x0000000199915ff0 __63-[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader _loadInitializationContext]_block_invoke + 72
    19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001970ae280 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001970522f4 _dispatch_once_callout + 28
    21  UIKitCore                       0x0000000199915fa4 -[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader _loadInitializationContext] + 120
    22  UIKitCore                       0x0000000199916248 __70-[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader startPreloadInitializationContext]_block_invoke + 24
    23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001970ad298 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    24  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001970ae280 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    25  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197060074 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 688
    26  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197060704 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 124
    27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dfbab568 _pthread_wqthread + 212
    28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dfbae874 start_wqthread + 8
    
    Thread 2 name:  JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c334c61c __psynch_cvwait + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dfba32fc _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 1180
    2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001ab87ae0c std::__1::condition_variable::wait+ 52748 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
    3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a0fe4b54 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >+ 14871380 (std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 108
    4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a0fe9584 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop+ 14890372 () + 252
    5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a0fe8f98 bmalloc::Scavenger::Scavenger+ 14888856 (std::__1::scoped_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> const&) + 0
    6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a0fea6c0 std::__1::__thread_specific_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct>::set_pointer+ 14894784 (std::__1::__thread_struct*) + 0
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dfba9b3c _pthread_start + 288
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dfbae880 thread_start + 8
    
    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dfbae86c start_wqthread + 0
    
    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
        x0: 0xfffffffffffffffc   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000001701   x3: 0x0000000000000000
        x4: 0x0000000000000010   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000023
        x8: 0x0000000000001307   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x00000001e629ece8  x11: 0x01e70001e629ece9
       x12: 0x0000000000ae2464  x13: 0x000061a1f0aa8465  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x00000001f0aa8460
       x16: 0x0000000000000203  x17: 0x0000000199915f2c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
       x20: 0x00000001f0ab8a80  x21: 0x0000000001000002  x22: 0x0000000000001701  x23: 0x0000000106015108
       x24: 0x000000016b009f90  x25: 0x00000001f0a4bdbc  x26: 0x0000000105293960  x27: 0x00000001f0aa8320
       x28: 0x000000000000000b   fp: 0x000000016b009e40   lr: 0x00000001970515a4
        sp: 0x000000016b009e20   pc: 0x00000001c334d290 cpsr: 0x00000000
       esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
    
    Binary Images:
    0x104df0000 - 0x104df7fff dragononlinemmorpg arm64  <de66ff8722fa329dae8296ae09bb3dd5> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/97F19A54-D4EA-4D20-94BA-DF88D87C9D8E/dragononlinemmorpg.app/dragononlinemmorpg
    0x104ebc000 - 0x104ec7fff FBSDKGamingServicesKit arm64  <9478b59ceaf3301f895f9a259ab82fa8> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/97F19A54-D4EA-4D20-94BA-DF88D87C9D8E/dragononlinemmorpg.app/Frameworks/FBSDKGamingServicesKit.framework/FBSDKGamingServicesKit
....
```

Comment: Also just got this log if it helps - 
Received termination request from [daemon<com.apple.SpringBoard>:61] on <RBSProcessPredicate <RBSProcessHandlePredicateImpl| application<nedi.game.dragononlinemmorpg>:572>> with context <RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:process-launch watchdog transgression: application<nedi.game.drago>:572 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 20.00 seconds

WatchdogCPUStatistics: (nlinemm
    "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 7.990 (user 7.990, system 0.000), 20% CPU",
    "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.049, 0% CPU"

Answer (score 0):

Your error code is: `0x8badf00d`

This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186258/app-crash-exception-type-exc-crash-sigkill-termination-reason-namespace-spri) and is likely related to the networking of your application; given in it's a `dragononlinemmorpg`.

Apple has documentation on how to [diagnose crash reports](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs)